# How does the following function call work in Javascript

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, scope

I've been playing with the code associated with [this really cool](http://www.code-magazine.com/article.aspx?quickid=1105081&page=5) article.

In the articles code a variable is assigned a function as follows:

```
var messageFactory = (function() {
    var that = {},
        $chatMessage = $('<p></p>').
          addClass('chat message'),
        $nick = $('<span></span>').
          addClass('nick'),
        $systemMessage = $('<p></p>').
          addClass('system message');

    var chat = function(message) {
      var $filledNick = $nick.clone().
            text(message.nick + ':');
      return $chatMessage.clone().
        append($filledNick).
        append(message.text);
    };

    var system = function(message) {
      return $systemMessage.clone().text(message.text);
    };

    that.chat = chat;
    that.system = system;

    return that;
  })();
```

Later sub functions are called like the following,

```
messageFactory.system({ text: 'You changed your nick to ' + nick + '.'})
```

and

```
messageFactory.chat({ nick: 'me', text: message })
```

What's going on in those calls? Specifically it appears that the var messageFactory is working similar to a class definition in language like C#, and I'm missing the scope related mechanisms to how the values are being passed via the object { text: '...' ...}.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first and arguably most important thing to note is the last line. Specifically, the `()` before the `;`. What this is doing is immediately executing the anonymous function on line 1. This is important to note because `messageFactory` will not contain the anonymous function, but rather whatever is returned from it. To better understand that, I'll give an example...

```
var x = (function(){ return "Hello!"; })();
// x will contain "Hello!", not the function.
```

The second thing to keep in mind is that objects in Javascript will maintain a reference to the closure that they were created in. So if you immediately execute a function like we're doing above, that will a form a closure and objects created in that closure will maintain a reference to it even after the function is done executing. Another example....

```
var sayHi = (function(){ 
    var salutation = "Hello";
    return function(name) {
       return salutation + ", " + name + ".";
    }
})();
```

Note again that we have an anonymous function being immediately executed. So the variable `sayHi` will not contain the outside anonymous function, but rather it's return value. So `sayHi` will actually contain `function(name){ return salutation + ", " + name + ".";}`. You'll note that we're not passing in `salutation`, but we can still access it as it's part of the `closure` that this function was created in.

The final thing to understand the provided code is that in Javascript, `{}` is an Object literal. It's essentially equivalent to saying `new Object()`. These objects can have properties and methods the same as a C# object, which is where the `.text` is coming from that you referred to.

On line 2, the code is creating an Object literal: `var that = {}`. The next var creation is `var chat = function(message){....` where a function is created which takes a `message` parameter and does some stuff with it. Towards the end of the code, that `chat` function is then assigned to the `chat` property of `that` and then `that` is returned: `that.chat = chat` and `return that`.

The point of all this is that `messageFactory` does not contain the function it appears to be assigned to, but rather the `return` of that function. In this case, that return is actually the `that` Object, which has two properties of `chat` and `system`. Those properties actually point back to the `chat` and `system` variables inside the same closure that `that` was created in, which makes this all work.

The final piece is simple enough.... when you call `messageFactory.chat({ text: 'something', nick:`Joe`})` you're actually passing an `Object` as a parameter to the `chat` function inside the closure. It then references the object's `nick` and `text` properties to return its result.

Hope that helps. I'm not sure I explained it very well, but that's kind of how it works in my head.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time for such a detailed response! That really cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 0):

It's anonymous class declaration and instantiation

http://jasonwyatt.tumblr.com/post/866536821/anonymous-classes-with-javascript-and-self-calling